# Electron NET response does not deliver headers periodically after Electron update to v21

Tags: rest, https, electron

Background: I am trying to contact to a server (like https: //myserver/file.exe) to receive an update of a file, if there is a new version of it. For that, i am taking the `last-modified` header parameter from the `response.headers` i am getting back from the request via `net` from `@electron/remote`.

This was working the way it should on old Electron versions (12.2.2 in this case), however, after a large update to Electron v21.0.1, there are pretty often no headers (but still data) delivered back. Logs would look like:

```
STATUS: 200
HEADERS: {}
data: Array(15)
```

Sometimes, headers are indeed delivered, but this is most likely one time out of ten attempts. "HEADERS" then is:

```
HEADERS: {"date":"Wed, 05 Oct 2022 12:22:42 GMT","etag":"\"633bc02a-aec01d\"","last-modified":"Tue, 04 Oct 2022 05:10:02 GMT","cache-control":"max-age=3600","cf-cache-status":"REVALIDATED","report-to":"{\"endpoints\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=CkyxJliNOH9rDYgSVpjID7NaTVlUkBH1tgJxibvzmTh%2BRpZBk0FeFf03oJuHateoQVnWJhqSn1FHNs2%2FB%2Fkc%2BDuiaAnt%2BKHmzRlGoAY%2BGDplpVJ1K%2BXVDITGmD0xeFRXtA%3D%3D\"}],\"group\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}","nel":"{\"success_fraction\":0,\"report_to\":\"cf-nel\",\"max_age\":604800}","vary":"Accept-Encoding","server":"cloudflare","cf-ray":"75561fd10c439b3d-FRA","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=86400, h3-29=\":443\"; ma=86400"}
```

Maybe interesting: Cloudflare is involved here. Similar requests via Postman work fluently.

Of course, this breaks the logic, as no last-modified parameter is usable anymore. Does anyone see causes and / or ways out? I would like to avoid a downgrade of Electron.

Below my code:

```
const { net } = require('@electron/remote');

...

checkUpdate() {
    const request = net.request({
        method: 'GET',
        protocol: 'https:',
        hostname: <myUrl>,
        port: 443,
        path: <myPath>
    });
    
    request.setHeader('x-abs-abcore-version', '1.00');
    request.setHeader('x-abs-abcore-type', 'crossplatform');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    
    request.on('response', (response) => {
    
        const data = []; 
    
        response.on('error', (e) => { 
            console.log(e);
        });
                    
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data.push(chunk)
        });
    
        response.on('end', () => {                            
            console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
            console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
            console.log("data",data)

            if (Date.parse(<localFilesLastModified>) < Date.parse(response.headers['last-modified'].toString())) { 
                //Do some update
            }
                              
                             
        });

        request.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
        
        request.end();
    });
}
```